# how to prevent vulnerability scanning

Tags: asp.net, security, web-crawler, error-reporting

I have a web site that reports about each non-expected server side error on my email.

Quite often (once each 1-2 weeks) somebody launches automated tools that bombard the web site with a ton of different URLs:

- sometimes they (hackers?) think my site has inside phpmyadmin hosted and they try to access vulnerable (i believe) php-pages...
- sometimes they are trying to access pages that are really absent but belongs to popular CMSs
- last time they tried to inject wrong ViewState...

It is clearly not search engine spiders as 100% of requests that generated errors are requests to invalid pages.

Right now they didn't do too much harm, the only one is that I need to delete a ton of server error emails (200-300)... But at some point they could probably find something.

I'm really tired of that and looking for the solution that will block such 'spiders'.

Is there anything ready to use? Any tool, dlls, etc... Or I should implement something myself?

In the 2nd case: could you please recommend the approach to implement? Should I limit amount of requests from IP per second (let's say not more than 5 requests per second and not more then 20 per minute)?

P.S. Right now my web site is written using ASP.NET 4.0.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: BTW, maybe you shouldn't be sending emails for every error. Log them where you can see them, and maybe email a summary of the errors.

Comment: I thought about this, but that will help me only deleting similar emails when my final goal is to prevent vulnerability scanning.

Comment: You can't control who makes requests to your server - you can only control which of those requests succeeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things what you can consider...

You can use one of the available Web Application Firewalls. It usually has set of rules and analytic engine that determine suspicious activities and react accordingly. For example in you case it can automatically block attempts to scan you site as it recognize it as a attack pattern.

More simple (but not 100% solution) approach is check referer url (referer url description in wiki) and if request was originating not from one of you page you rejected it (you probably should create httpmodule for that purpose).

And of cause you want to be sure that you site address all known security issues from OWASP TOP 10 list ([OWASP TOP 10](http://owasptop10.googlecode.com/files/OWASP%20Top%2010%20-%202010.pdf)). You can find very comprehensive description how to do it for asp.net here ([owasp top 10 for .net book in pdf](http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/12/free-ebook-owasp-top-10-for-net.html)), i also recommend to read the blog of the author of the aforementioned book: http://www.troyhunt.com/

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a good reference. Will go through it.

Comment: The referrer URL can easily be changed by the client.  It should not be trusted at all.

Comment: @Freedom_Ben That's why i said that it's not 100% solution. But you have to implement it in any way as it bring additional defense in any way and if your website will be penetration tested you will get feedback in penetration test report indicating that you have to do it if you didn't do it. So yes, not a 100% but you have implement it.

Answer (score 3):

Such bots are not likely to find any vulnerabilities in your system, if you just keep the server and software updated. They are generally just looking for low hanging fruit, i.e. systems that are not updated to fix known vulnerabilities.

You could make a bot trap to minimise such traffic. As soon as someone tries to access one of those non-existant pages that you know of, you could stop all requests from that IP address with the same browser string, for a while.

Comment: His browser string is Mozilla/4.0 (or something like this) so I can't really block by this criteria. And I do block such scanners by IP. My first thought about that was that they will just change their proxy and continue, but looks like it is not the case: blocking each such scanner by IP does really block them from repetitive scans :) But that's more a reaction, not a prevention. And I agree with you, the probability they will find a security whole is low... but I would better take some actions than just cross fingers :)

Comment: @Budda: What I meant was that you should use the combination of IP address and browser string in the block. Several users can be on the same IP address, and of course have the same browser, but using them in combination minimises the risk to block someone innocent. Especially as many such scripts use a library and don't change the default string, so they are not the same as for any real user.

Answer (score 2):

Theres nothing you can do (reliabily) to prevent ***vulernability scanning***, the only thing to do really is to make sure you are on top of any vulnerabilities and prevent ***vulernability exploitation***.

If youre site is only used by a select few and in constant locations you could maybe use an IP restriction

Comment: Web site is public and should be accessible for everybody so I can't restrict by IP. Thanks for an idea anyway.